# Freeze meat before or after cooking?

Tags: meat, freezing

If I am not going to immediately eat meat, should I freeze it before or after cooking it? How is taste and freshness affected by your choice of when to freeze it? I've done both options, but I've never compared the final preparation side by side.

Answer (score 9):

For whole cuts of meat such as a steak or a chicken breast, I find it's better to freeze without cooking. These cuts aren't as moist after thawing them and re-heating.

For ground meat, it doesn't seem to matter. If I have the time I will cook and then freeze to save myself the effort durring the week.